# W204 C180 Manifold absolute pressure sensor

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, sensor, intake-manifold

I am trying to install a RaceChip unit in my car. I need to find the Manifold absolute pressure sensor. I am aware that it’s near the air box, but I can’t find it.

Here is where it should be:

[image]

Here is my image:

[image]

As you can see, it’s not here. Does anyone know where it is on a W204 C class 1.6litre CGI engine.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Wow, that's wild, lol. It's gotta be somewhere, eh? :o)